# combining the vectors to and form a 12x2 matrix

Tags: r

```
a <- c(20,30,40,50)
b <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
```

For the above vectors, I wanted to combine each value in vector "a" with each of element "b" 1 value in "b" and form a 12x2 matrix.

Desired result:

```
       x y
 [1,] 20 1
 [2,] NA 2
 [3,] NA 3
 [4,] 30 1
 [5,] NA 2
 [6,] NA 3
 [7,] 40 1
 [8,] NA 2
 [9,] NA 3
[10,] 50 1
[11,] NA 2
[12,] NA 3
```

Comment: Perhaps `outer(c(a), b[1], FUN= paste)`

Comment: The title of the question is pretty misleading. Please change the title of the question so that it gives a better insight to the asked question.

Comment: "Combine" how? And so you end up with a 4x12 matrix or a 12x4 matrix?

Comment: @akrun, Thank you. I wanted to have a data frame that includes vector a and vector b, where elements of vector a are sorted if vector b is 1. Something like this, but without NA.           x y
 [1,] 20 1
 [2,] NA 2
 [3,] NA 3
 [4,] 30 1
 [5,] NA 2
 [6,] NA 3
 [7,] 40 1
 [8,] NA 2
 [9,] NA 3
[10,] 50 1
[11,] NA 2
[12,] NA 3

Comment: Please update your post with the expected output based on the example you showed

Comment: @akrun,@Spacedman,@Kunal, I have updated the question.

Comment: May be `library(rowr);do.call(rbind,lapply(a, function(x) cbind.fill(x, unique(b), fill=NA)))`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to match the values in `a` with the `b` values that are equal to 1.

Here's my idea.  Create a vector of NAs and replace the indices where `b == 1` with the values from `a`.  Then create the matrix.

```
matrix(
    c(replace(NA_real_[seq_along(b)], b == 1, a), b), 
    ncol = 2, 
    dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y"))
)
#        x y
#  [1,] 20 1
#  [2,] NA 2
#  [3,] NA 3
#  [4,] 30 1
#  [5,] NA 2
#  [6,] NA 3
#  [7,] 40 1
#  [8,] NA 2
#  [9,] NA 3
# [10,] 50 1
# [11,] NA 2
# [12,] NA 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the target matrix with the `x` value equal to `NA` then replace the entries that you need from `a`:

```
mb <- cbind(x=NA, y=b)
mb[mb[,'y'] ==1, 'x'] <- a
mb
##        x y
##  [1,] 20 1
##  [2,] NA 2
##  [3,] NA 3
##  [4,] 30 1
##  [5,] NA 2
##  [6,] NA 3
##  [7,] 40 1
##  [8,] NA 2
##  [9,] NA 3
## [10,] 50 1
## [11,] NA 2
## [12,] NA 3
```